# implementing a ChipGroup with adapter pattern

Tags: android, adapter, material-components-android, android-chips

My fragment contains a `ChipGroup` with the `chips` being added dynamically based on the users choice. What I wish to accomplish is an adapter pattern where a `list` is exposed to the adapter from which `chips` are being created user gets to add/remove the elements to and from the list.

I couldn't find any way to do that and right now, whenever the user interacts with the list, all the chips are recreated.

Code has been clipped for the sake of brevity

**XML file**

```
// capturing the user's choice
      <RadioGroup
          android:id="@+id/vehicles_radio_group"
          android:onCheckedChanged="@{vehicleViewModel::radioCheckedChanged}">
```

**ViewModel**

```
fun radioCheckedChanged(radioGroup: RadioGroup, checkedId: Int) {

        //validating the user's choice
            if (condition) {
                //code for adding the choice to a List
                vehicleDispatched(selectedVehicle, checkedId)   
            } else {
                selectionError()
            }
    }

    // adding the user's choice to the list
    // _dispatchingUnits is a LiveData

    private fun vehicleDispatched(selectedVehicle: DomainVehicle, checkedId: Int) {
  
     // appending the selected choice to the list(Type : List<Pair<Vehicle,Planet>>)
        _dispatchingUnits.value =
            _dispatchingUnits.value?.plus(selectedVehicle to _currentPlanet.value!!)
                ?: listOf(selectedVehicle to _currentPlanet.value!!)
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
// register an observer and take action

        myViewModel.dispatchingUnits.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { allPairs ->
            allPairs?.apply {

                with(binding) {
                   // remove the existing chips if any
                    if (selectedPairChipGroup.isNotEmpty()) {
                        selectedPairChipGroup.removeAllViews()
                    }
                  // create new chips
                    allPairs.forEach { chipPair ->
                        createChips(chipPair)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Expecting something like,

```
// In fragment class
val adapter = ChipAdapter()
binding.chipGroup.setAdapter(adapter)


// In bindingUtils file
@BindingAdapter("fill_data")
fun RecyclerChipGroup.setData(list : MyListType){
val adapter = this.adapter as ChipAdapter
adapter.submitChipList(list)
}

//XML File
<RecyclerChipGroup
....
app:fill_data = "@{viewModel.dispatchingUnits}"
....
/>
```

how to go on with it?

Comment: for multiple chips changing dynamically, you can use material chips (https://material.io/components/chips). for creating an adapter for chips you can visit http://www.douevencode.com/articles/2017-06/material-chips-list-with-chipslayoutmanag

Comment: I have indeed used material chips to display the users choice, and the later link seems to be broken

Comment: Ohh okay.  That link mentioned https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager this repo that uses recycler view layout manager. if you don't want to use a library in your project then the concept to do this is to create a recycler view and its adapter with chips instead of using chipGroup as it will provide all the features of recycler view and more flexibility than chipGroup.

Comment: Thanks for the link, quite useful, Thought of the same, just to use a `recyclerview` instead of `chipgroup` but that leaves me a question unanswered, Why have a `chipgroup` in the first place if we can go with `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Yes, recycler view and chipGroup have different use cases and as you mentioned in your question, you needed an adapter based list of chips. and since chipGroup does not have an adapter so RecyclerView is the best way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve adapter based list of chips and more controls than ChipGroup then you can use RecyclerView with chips as an item and to arrange chips in Left-to-Right or Right-to-Left order, you can create a custom LayoutManager.

For more details, you can visit https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager. This library provides support for ChipsLayoutManager.